# How do I make an HTML table from a database table?

Tags: php, database, html, wp-list-table

is there a built-in wordpress function to make the HTML or should I use plain-old PHP?

Comment: See also comment here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17615

Comment: See also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17661/how-to-use-wp-default-post-list-tables-in-a-plugin

Comment: See also: http://phpdoc.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/WordPress/List_Table/WP_Plugins_List_Table.html

Comment: Sorry misread the question. Thought it was XML. Please ignore my crazy answer. In fact, I'll delete it my self.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since 3.1 there's a class [`WP_List_Table`](http://phpdoc.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/WordPress/List_Table/WP_Plugins_List_Table.html) which makes it a hella lot easier to render tables for an array of data objects.

There's very little documentation (read: none) on it yet, but you can [check out the source](http://phpdoc.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/WordPress/List_Table/WP_Plugins_List_Table.html) if you're familiar with PHP.

Comment: A good example of representing a random database table in \admin using new \WP_List_Table would be nice I think. There is not so much out there except for scribu's code in track. Maybe nice for the wiki.

Comment: (so the code to use for the intermediate solution while the api is not there)

Comment: e.g.: http://code.google.com/p/nextgen-gallery/source/browse/trunk/admin/manage-galleries.php?r=937

Comment: or e.g. http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/google-affiliate-network/tags/4.0/GAN.php or http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/15386/my-list-table-plugin.php

Comment: +1 ... but as @Rarst said: The class will change and get an API with the next versions.